# Хочу сортировать комментарии по Дате добавления

Tags: html, python, django

Нужно сортировать комментарии с начало новые чтобы они были сверху а потом старые, то есть они были ниже новых. Если нужно то views и urls тоже скину

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    dates = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Comment


class NameForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name','text',)
```

шаблон html

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <br>
    {% if comments %}
    {% for comment in comments %}
    <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="Comment">
      <div class="panel-heading" id="CommentHead">
          <h1>{{ comment.name }}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          <h3> {{ comment.text }}</h3>
          <h3 {{ comment.dates }}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-dates']
```

[Соответствующий раздел](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) документации.

Comment: Спасибо сработало

Comment: @NeIT отметь, что правильный ответ